# Fetching selected columns from a wide (> 255 columns) SQL Server table into MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have some VBA code that analyzes data in MS Access. Some of the data is in a SQL Server (linked within Access).

My issue is that this particular table has too many columns (255+), so Access truncates some of the columns that are relevant to me.

My thought was that I can pull the relevant data (I only need 10 or so columns) using ADO (or DAO), save it in my access table and move on with the rest of the logic.

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim ssql as String
cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=CID;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
ssql = "SELECT a.channel, a.Firm_Name, a.[AUM 0915], a.[Rev 0915] INTO [Localtable] FROM dbo.TableName"
cn.execute (ssql)
```

I could get the Recordset and then loop through it, though not keen on doing that (it's a few hundred thousand rows of data, which makes it really slow). What I am hoping for is a solution that either

1. (preferably) Does it all in a single SQL statement
2. (I'll take this) Dumps the whole Recordset into Access (hopefully efficiently)

Appreciate any pointers. Here are my additional constraints

1. I don't have any say in how the data is stored in SQL Server itself, so I can't ask anyone to reduce the number of columns
2. I only have read permission on the SQL server, so I can't create a new table on the server and then link it through Access

Thanks.

Comment: Can you ask a DBA to create a view which pulls those 10 columns from the wide table and then link to that view in Access?

Comment: When you say, "Does it all in a single SQL statement", what is "it"?

Comment: You could use an Access pass-through query (using the same SELECT statement as in your question) to retrieve only the columns you need. The recordset produced by the pass-through query would be read-only, but you could always dump that into a temporary table in Access if necessary.

Comment: @Hansup: I unfortunately don't have that option (that's my constraint #1)

Comment: @TomH by "it" I meant pull all my relevant fields (and data) from SQL server, and dump them into my local Access database.

Comment: @GordThompson, are you able to point to some simple code that dumps a Recordset into Access?

Comment: Say you [create a pass-through query](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Process-SQL-on-a-database-server-by-using-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42) and name it [myPassThroughQuery]. You could then use a make-table query like `SELECT * INTO [myLocalTable] FROM [myPassThroughQuery]` to dump the contents into a local Access table.

Comment: @GordThompson, thanks a lot. That's a very simple and elegant solution. I was too fixated on VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward way to accomplish your goal would be to [create a pass-through query](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Process-SQL-on-a-database-server-by-using-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42) using the SELECT statement cited in the question. The pass-through query is executed on the SQL Server and therefore is not restricted to the first 255 columns of the SQL Server table, as would be the case for an ODBC linked table in Access.

The recordset produced by a pass-through SELECT query will be read-only. If that proved to be inconvenient when using it in other queries (i.e., by tripping over "Query must use an updateable recordset" errors) then you could always use a make-table query to dump the results of the pass-through query into a local Access table:

```sql
SELECT * INTO [myLocalTable] FROM [myPassThroughQuery]
```